# How to set the background color of a List in a NavigationView

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationview

Consider a `NavigationView` containing a `List` of items. How does one give this a background color?

- Putting the `NavigationView` in a `ZStack` - doesn't work
- Putting the `ZStack` in the `NavigationView` (code sample below) - doesn't work

```
struct test: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.blue
                List {
                    ForEach(["1", "2", "3"], id: \.self) { item in
                        NavigationLink(destination: EmptyView()) {
                            Text("Some title")
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Items")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: background color of list in navigationview - not working]

Comment: Does this your answere? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67941522/14733292

Answer (score 0):

- Combine putting the ZStack inside the NavigationView with setting the appearance of UITableView `onAppear` of the List.
- Set `.listRowBackground` on the ForEach to have the cells get the same background color.

```
struct test: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.blue.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                List {
                    ForEach(["1", "2", "3"], id: \.self) { item in
                        NavigationLink(destination: EmptyView()) {
                            Text("Some title")
                        }
                    }.listRowBackground(Color.blue)
                }
                .onAppear() {
                    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                    UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                }
                .navigationTitle("Items")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: background color of list in navigationview - working]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the appearance of every `List` and `Form` in your app, you can use [SwiftUI-Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect).

I changed the list row background color in SwiftUI, and set the background with Introspect so it *only* affects this `List` and no other.

Code:

```
NavigationView {
    List {
        ForEach(["1", "2", "3"], id: \.self) { item in
            NavigationLink(destination: EmptyView()) {
                Text("Some title")
            }
            .listRowBackground(Color.blue)
        }
    }
    .introspectTableView { tableView in
        tableView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
    }
    .navigationTitle("Items")
}
```

*Note: UIKit's `.systemBlue` is equivalent to SwiftUI's `.blue`.*