# removing background color from list in swiftui

Tags: swift, list, swiftui

This is how my UI looks right now:

[image: Current UI]

I want to remove this white background from my List, I have tried changing foreground and background colors of my list to Color.clear, I have also tried adding .listRowBackgroundColor to my list items, but this doesn't remove all of the background, this is my current code:

```
                            VStack(spacing: 30) {
                                
                                List(0 ..< 10) { item in
                                    Button(action: {
                                        print("stisa si za kafic")
                                    }, label: {
                                        CafeBarTab() 
                                }).listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                                }
                                .background(Color("background-Color"))
                                .foregroundColor(Color("background-Color"))
                                .frame(width: 400, height: 5000, alignment: .leading)
                            }
```

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/67941522/14733292

Comment: tried that, didn't work