# How to change the listRowBackground of a collapsible List in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a similar or same issue [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67940790/it-appears-impossible-to-make-the-background-of-an-expandable-list-transparent) but [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67941522/3581788) is definitely not the answer.

[Using Hacking With Swift's example](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-expanding-lists):

```swift
struct Bookmark: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let icon: String
    var items: [Bookmark]?

    // some example websites
    static let apple = Bookmark(name: "Apple", icon: "1.circle")
    static let bbc = Bookmark(name: "BBC", icon: "square.and.pencil")
    static let swift = Bookmark(name: "Swift", icon: "bolt.fill")
    static let twitter = Bookmark(name: "Twitter", icon: "mic")

    // some example groups
    static let example1 = Bookmark(name: "Favorites", icon: "star", items: [Bookmark.apple, Bookmark.bbc, Bookmark.swift, Bookmark.twitter])
    static let example2 = Bookmark(name: "Recent", icon: "timer", items: [Bookmark.apple, Bookmark.bbc, Bookmark.swift, Bookmark.twitter])
    static let example3 = Bookmark(name: "Recommended", icon: "hand.thumbsup", items: [Bookmark.apple, Bookmark.bbc, Bookmark.swift, Bookmark.twitter])
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let items: [Bookmark] = [.example1, .example2, .example3]

    var body: some View {
        List(items, children: \.items) { row in
            Image(systemName: row.icon)
            Text(row.name)
        }
    }
}
```

List should be collapsible with the ability to change `listRowBackground`. Is this possible? I'm now wondering if `Bookmark.items` should be some view with the modifier `.listRowBackground(..)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to `listRowBackground` interface contract:

```
var body: some View {
    List {
        OutlineGroup(items, children: \.items) { row in
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: row.icon)
                Text(row.name)
            }
        }.listRowBackground(Color.red)
    }
}
```

Everything else is the same as in referenced question/answer.

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

Comment: Can we change background color of Subitems? and Can we set some space between two section?